# I am trying to add the ios platform and getting error, how to fix it?

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to run

`ionic cordova platform add ios`

And getting the following error:

```
Building project: /Users/pritambanerjee/Documents/***/fileUpload/platforms/ios/fileUpload.xcworkspace

    Configuration: Debug
    Platform: emulator
Build settings from command line:
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/pritambanerjee/Documents/******/fileUpload/platforms/ios/build/emulator
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator11.2
    SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /Users/pritambanerjee/Documents/******/fileUpload/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

Build settings from configuration file '/Users/pritambanerjee/Documents/******/fileUpload/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig':
    CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = YES
    CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Entitlements-$(CONFIGURATION).plist
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer
    ENABLE_BITCODE = NO
    GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = DEBUG=1
    HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/lib/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include" "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)"
    OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC
    SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Bridging-Header.h

xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
        { platform:iOS Simulator, OS:latest, name:iPhone 5s }

    The requested device could not be found because no available devices matched the request.

    Ineligible destinations for the "fileUpload" scheme:
        { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Generic iOS Device }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Generic iOS Simulator Device }
Error: Error code 70 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/pritambanerjee/Documents/*******/fileUpload/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,fileUpload.xcworkspace,-scheme,fileUpload,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 5s,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/pritambanerjee/Documents/PeerHealthWorkspace/fileUpload/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/pritambanerjee/Documents/PeerHealthWorkspace/fileUpload/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by running:

```
ionic cordova build ios --device
```